# How do you move prisoners?

Tags: rimworld

When capturing prisoners, they appear to be randomly assigned prisoner beds. However, after I have perused their stats, I usually want to manually assign them more appropriate rooms in order to provide medical care and/or recruit them.

For normal beds (for the colonists), there is the "set owner" option. How do I do this for prisoners?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a trick for moving prisoners to specific beds.

1. Mark all non-occupied prisoner beds for colonists, except the one you want to move them into.
2. Mark the prisoner's current bed as for colonists.
3. A warden should come move the prisoner to their new bed shortly.
4. For a room with more than one prisoner, manually order a warden to take the prisoner to bed. Then you can turn the room back into a prison cell for the remaining prisoner(s).

   - A constructor can move the prisoner's bed, and then a warden will come to move them.

Comment: That's a decent suggestion, but isn't there a limitation that prevents colonist beds and prisoner beds to exist in the same room? In that case, I will have to make every holding cell single occupancy in order to do that. I would hope to have a general holding area and then "upgrading" the prisoners that had specific medical/convenience needs to better accommodations.

Comment: Yes, that is true - I do single occupancy cells, so I forgot that entire rooms are categorized and not just beds. FWIW I do the single occupancy to prevent one enraged prisoner from killing everyone.

Answer (score 4):

If they are still injured, I haven't found a way to move them, but once they are healthy, you can kick them out of their current bed by marking it for Medical, and then a colonist will come along and escort them to a different (still random) bed.

By marking all of the Unoccupied beds as Medical except for one, you can force the prisoner into that particular bed.